# Serial port read() not returning when data is available (python/cygwin)

Tags: python, cygwin, pyserial

I'm using Cygwin on the PC to access the serial port using pySerial.
My comport is a USB comport connected to a device that responds to queries.
We have 36 comports and I am using COM36 (/dev/ttyS35).

Given our libraries, I need to keep using python 2.7.
I do a read() on the port and it always waits until exactly the length of the data I request is read rather than returning when data is available like it would in C++.

Using the 'timeout' parameter isn't an option, because it would force it to wait for the timeout every single time. Too short and it misses data and spins taking up processor time, and too long and it slows the program down. I know in my C++ apps that the libraries wait until at least one byte is read and continues to read more until there is a 'significant' pause between bytes read before returning. I want the behavior in python.

I thought I had found my answer when I saw the 'interCharTimeout' of the Serial constructor, but that didn't work. It still hung until all 100 bytes were read.
I then looked in the PySerial code and it looked like it was not setting the right var (I could be wrong) in the object, so I called the 'setInterCharTimeout' method directly. But still the same result.

Here is my simple code example.

```
#!/bin/env python

import serial
from lib.Hex import *

# COM35, a USB serial port
s = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyS34", baudrate=19200, interCharTimeout=0.01)
s.close()
s.open()
s.setInterCharTimeout( 0.01 )
s.setTimeout( 2 )

# Send message the causes the device to generate a reply
data = fromHex( "AABB01072851EE" )
s.write( data )

data = s.read(100) # Note: this does return data if 'timeout' was used
print "Got: ", toHex(data)
```

I read the posixserial.py code and I saw that Serial always looped till all the bytes were read. I then saw that there was PosixPollSerial which overrode read(). I tried to use that.

```
 s = serial.PosixPollSerial(port="/dev/ttyS34", baudrate=19200, interCharTimeout=0.1)
```

But the I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./go2.py", line 18, in <module>
  data = s.read(100)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 672, in read
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Line 672 in serialposix.py is this:

```
672                 for fd, event in poll.poll(self._timeout*1000):
```

Comment: I fixed it. I wanted it to be blocking. I wanted to avoid polling or unnecessarily using a select mechanism.
The base code in the read call in pySerial did, in fact, return when data was ready, however, the logic kept looping until the buffer was filled... who the heck ever wants that, especially from a streaming serial port. Dumb!
Anyway, I rewrote for myself that portion of pySerial, to return the data when the base code returned from gathering available data, and whalaaa. exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

> **pySerial 3.0 documentation**: [serial.Serial.in_waiting](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting)
>   **in_waiting**
>       Getter: Get the number of bytes in the input buffer
>       Type:   int
>       Return the number of bytes in the receive buffer.
>       Changed in version 3.0: changed to property from inWaiting()

For instance, read all waiting or at least 1 `serial.in_waiting or 1`.

```
B_SIZE = 10

def RxEvent(b):
    print('RxEvent(%s) %d' % (b, len(b)))

def Thread_serial_read(serial, alive, rxEvent):
    serial.timeout = 0.5  # make sure that the alive event can be checked from time to time
    n = 0
    b_tmp = []
    while alive.isSet():
        time.sleep(0.25)
        b = serial.read(serial.in_waiting or 1)
        if b:
            b_tmp.extend(b)
            n += len(b)
            if n >= B_SIZE:
                rxEvent( b_tmp[:B_SIZE] )
                b_tmp = b_tmp[B_SIZE:]
                n = len(b_tmp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alive = threading.Event()
    Thread_serial_read(Serial(), alive, RxEvent)
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Comment: Again, due to my constraints, I can't use python 3. All our vast libraries work on Python 2.7 and too much has changed to do this...

Comment: My bad, you mean **pySerial 2.7**instead of **Python 2.7**. Couldn't imagine that the difference between  **pySerial 2.7 and 3** is to much, will check this.

Comment: From CHANGES.rst: _Version 3.0a0 2015-09-22

    Starting from this release, only Python 2.7 and 3.2 (or newer) are supported. **The source code is compatible to the 2.x and 3.x series without any changes.**_

Comment: This is incorrect. print itself has changed. 

    $ python2.7
    Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 18:05:38)
    [GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
    >>> print "abc", "def"
    abc def
    >>> print ("abc","def")
    ('abc', 'def')
    >>>
    $ python3.4
    Python 3.4.3 (default, May  5 2015, 17:58:45)
    [GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
    >>> print "abc", "def"
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "abc", "def"
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
    >>> print ("abc","def")
    abc def

Comment: @MarshallJobe: Feel free to use **Python 2.7**, my example code  run also with this Version of Python.